# How to install drivers for iogear smart card reader?

Tags: command-line, drivers, usb

I'm still trying to learn how to use the terminal in 13.04.  I downloaded the Linux drivers for the hardware and began reading the installation and immediately got lost.

http://www.iogear.com/support/dm/driver/GSR202#display

If anybody could help me out that would be great. I don't know if the instructions are written with the files saved in a different location (I extracted the folder to my desktop) or if I am just completely lost.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow **EXACTLY/EACH** the instruction given by manufacturer, 
in terminal,

1. command `cd Desktop` 
   in terminal to **change the working directory where your .zip file is to desktop**

**OR** you can just download again in **default** location in terminal and you don't have to change directory `cd`

in terminal, type

wget http://www.iogear.com/support/driver/GSR202_Linux_Driver.zip

1. follow the instruction given,
2. `tar zxvf  libusb-0.1.12.tar.gz` --- **this to extract**
3. `cd libusb-0.1.12`---**change the directory to the extracted folder**
4. `./configure`---**configuration file is ready for 'make'**
5. `sudo make install`---**enter your root password**
6. Follow the same step for other installation

During `make`, **make sure there is no error in this stage then you can proceed with `make install`** please fix any error that you encounter first, install manually packages that required if needed (it's dependencies), do search in **Software Center** for needed packages and install them first! then try `make` again.

```
-------------------cut from the driver installation instruction--------------

=====================================================
=                                                   =
=      Alcormicro Smart card reader                 =
=    Linux TARBALL Package Release Note             =
=                               =
=====================================================

If the version of  libusb is under 0.1.9 , it need to update to latest one.
Otherwise skip  step1.

=========================================
[Optional]
Step1. Install  libusb

 # tar zxvf  libusb-0.1.12.tar.gz 
 # cd libusb-0.1.12                          
 # ./configure                             
 # make                                    
 # make install          ( Login as a root to install driver )          
========================================= 

Step2. Install  pcsc-lite

 # PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig;export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
 # LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

 # tar xjf pcsc-lite-1.5.5.tar.bz2
 # cd pcsc-lite-1.5.5
 # ./configure --disable-libhal
 # make                                    
 # make install          (Login as a root to install driver)

Step3. Install ccid driver

 # tar zxvf ccid-1.3.12_alcormicro.tar.gz
 # cd ccid-1.3.12_alcormicro
 # PCSC_LIBS="-L/usr/local/lib -lpcsclite" ./configure --enable-usbdropdir=/usr/local/pcsc/drivers --disable-pcsclite
 # make                                    
 # make install          (Login as a root to install driver)

 Note:
    Make sure pkg-config already installed.
    ./pcscd
    Add PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin

-----------------------cut from the driver installation instruction------------
```

Hope it help!